# Use image path instead of base64 image data URI while saving canvas in json in fabric js

Tags: database, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to save the editable state of fabric js canvas in a database, I tried to do so by converting it into json and saving it in database to an attribute of data type BLOB. When more than one image is added to the canvas, the length of the json exceeds the limit of BLOB as the json uses image data URI. So, is there a way to change this data URI to the specific image path? Or are there any alternatives to this problem?

Comment: Are you using `fabric.Image.fromURL` to load your images?

Comment: Yes, `fabric.Image.fromURL` to load the image

Comment: check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJ9MC/197/), it contains only image path

Comment: Thanks, so this means I have to get the path of the image through input type file, before loading it on canvas using `fabric.Image.fromURL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use [`fromUrl`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#.fromURL) to load and image:

```
var URL = 'http://somedomain.com';

fabric.Image.fromURL(URL, function (oImg) {
    canvas.add(oImg);
    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

Comment: I have replaced the URL with my image base64 string. it works perfectly